# How do I get the class of a parent in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I get the name of the class in the parent ? I have "test stuff" and therefore can get it's parent. Once I have the parent. how do I get the class property?

```
<div class="ABC">test stuff</div>
```

`$(this).parent()` - gets the DIV with class ABC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).parent().attr('class')` is a way to do it. If the element could potentially have more than one class, you might find the [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method better.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent()[0].className;
$(this).parent().attr("class");
```

Also check out the other class manipulation functions.

1. [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass)
2. [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass)
3. [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass)

Comment: can `.parent()` return more then one result?

Comment: Only if the $("originalObject") has more than one element in it. It gets the parent of each element in the child elements.

Comment: @Erik, yes it returns a collection based on the selector. In the OP's case, it *should* only return one.

Comment: actually in this case it can't -- `$(this)` can't be a collection.

Comment: That's what he said. `"In the OP's case, it should only return one"`